# Install iBall 3.5G connect Modem on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 64-bit, usb-modem, modem

I've searched a lot to resolve my issue on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com), but my problem persists.
(So there is no issue of duplicate topic)

I installed Ubuntu Latest Version (18.04.1) on my Laptop (Dell Inspiron 15R 5521) with x64 bit.

Now I have iBall 3.5G Modem,

Specifications:-
Model: iBall 3.5GH - 72
Version: 3.1.0

Compatible OS': WinXP, Vista (32 bit/64 Bit), Win7 (32 bit/64 bit), Win8 (32 bit/64 bit), Mac OS X 10.5 upto 10.8 (Intel Platform)
[More Details Here...](https://www.iball.co.in/Product/3-5G-Connect---3GH---72/80)

Now in this List nowhere Linux is written, but as this is only way (modem) to have internet access for me in Ubuntu, it is compulsory to install this Modem in my Ubuntu anyhow...

So, How can I install this Windows and MAC supported Modem on my Ubuntu OS.

Thanks in Advance!

PS: I run both OS (Win8.1 & Ubuntu) on my PC.

Without Plugging Device
`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

After plugging Device
`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1c9e:f000 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Let's start by identifying the exact device. With the device inserted, open a terminal and run the command: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Dear @chili555 added more info to ques.

Comment: *1c9e:f000 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY* This is a usb-modeswitch device. Please be certain that usb-modeswitch is installed: `sudo dpkg -s usb-modeswitch | grep Status` If it is installed, please remove the device and run from the terminal: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` Insert the device. Copy and paste the resulting output so that you can post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c.

Comment: Thanks for Quick Response @chili555 [Here are the Results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7X8CT5wRxd/)

Comment: I believe there was a misunderstanding. I meant: 1. unplug the device; 2. In terminal: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` ; 3. plug *in* the device; 4. capture the 10-15 lines that appear in syslog. That doesn't appear to be the sequence that you followed.

Comment: I want to inform you that I've now took a new Airtel Hotspot, so that now I can connect o it Wireless thank you so much for your help....